# MySQL: Condición para ordenar de una misma columna definida

Tags: mysql, sql, aplicación-web

Estoy teniendo un problema para realizar un ordenamiento en MySQL.

Haciendo lo siguiente:

```
select
   o1.id as obj_id,
   "Objeto" as obj_pkg from objetos1 o1
where .... 
union select 
   o2.id as obj_id, 
   "Objeto2" as obj_pkg from objetos2 o2 
where ...
order by ( select count(*)
           from puntuaciones p
           where p.obj_pkg = obj_pkg ) desc;
```

El problema que estoy teniendo en el orden es en **p.obg_pkg = obg_pkg**, como en la tabla puntuaciones hay una columna que se llama **obj_pkg** no me toma la condición de que sea como la columna que estoy definiendo en el select ( que tiene casualmente el mismo nombre ).
Se que una solución es cambiar "Objeto" as **obj_pkg** a otro nombre (ej. pkg).
Pero estoy buscando otra alternativa, me ayudan?

Gracias!

*Nota: El código que puse es representativo.*

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? He probado una SELECT parecida y no me da ningún error

Comment: Ese es el problema, no me da ningun error. Toma que esta comparación p.obg_pkg = obg_pkg es de igual a igual y no me da el resultado que espero.

Comment: @Tomichemm ¿Y que resultado esperas?

Comment: @Tomichemm cuando digo que no me da ningún error me refiero a que la consulta funciona sin problemas y devuelve valores

Comment: Funciona sin problemas, es mas, da un resultado,pero no es el esperado, en el ejemplo que puse esperaría los distintos objetos ordenados por puntuación ( de mayor a menor ).
Agrego una aclaracion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución.
Si se realizan uniones se debe ordenar por una columna generada en las uniones. Es muy probable que no funcione de otra manera. Fuente: [Documentacion de MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).

Por lo tanto, el codigo tiene que quedar:

```
select
  o1.id as obj_id,
  ( select count(*) from puntuaciones p where p.obj_pkg = "Objeto" and p.objeto_id = o1.id ) as puntos,
  "Objeto" as obj_pkg from objetos1 o1
where .... 
union select 
  o2.id as obj_id,  
  ( select count(*) from puntuaciones p where p.obj_pkg = "Objeto2" and p.objeto_id = o2.id ) as puntos,
  "Objeto2" as obj_pkg from objetos2 o2
where ...
order by puntos desc;
```